# Given that the line $y=mx$, where $m$ is a real constant, is invariant under $T$, find the two possible values of $m$.

Tags: matrices, geometry

Given that the line $y=mx$, where $m$ is a real constant, is invariant under $T$, find the two possible values of $m$. The matrix $T$ is represented by $2×2$ matrix $\begin{bmatrix} -3 & 0\\ 0 & -3\end{bmatrix}$.

**My approach:** I multiplied the matrix represented by $T$ and $[x\ mx]$ and got $[-3x\ -3mx]$. So, I thought that all the points at $[x\ mx]$ have moved to $[-3x\ -3mx]$ and they have all moved to another point but the same line $y=m(-3x)$ which means that regardless of the value of m the line will remain invariant.

However the answer is $m=\pm 1$ and doesn't seem to include the infinite aspect. I probably have something wrong in my rationale it would be appreciated for someone to clear this up.

Comment: I think that your answer is correct for the question as you have written it. Are you sure that you haven't transposed the matrix?

Comment: Not at all, i really don't know where i have went wrong

Comment: The answer includes the part of multiplying the matrix represented by T and [x mx] and the result becoming [-3x -3mx] and then says that [-3x -3mx] lies on the line y mx = for m = 1 and m = −1, so the line is invariant
under T for these two values of m .

Answer (score 1):

Geometrically, the transformation matrix $$T = \begin{bmatrix}-3 & 0 \\ 0 & -3 \end{bmatrix} = -3 I_2,$$ where $I_2$ is the $2 \times 2$ identity matrix, represents a dilation by a factor of $-3$.  This of course is also equivalent to the composition of a reflection about the origin with a dilation by a factor of $3$.  Therefore, any line through the origin is mapped to itself under $T$, although the mapping is not order-preserving due to the negative sign.